# TabView header style

Tags: nativescript, tabview

I am using TabVIew and I’ve got two questions:
1.How can I remove the border-bottom of the TabView header?
2. How can I add separator between the items in the TabView header ?

[image: Example]

Thanks,
Chen

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove neither the bottom color nor add a separator within the tabs. You can control the color of your bottom border for the **selected** tab. Here are the exposed properties in NativeScript

```
<TabView 
    androidSelectedTabHighlightColor="orange" 
    selectedTabTextColor="red" 
    tabBackgroundColor="lightgreen" 
    tabTextColor="blue">
```

For anything above that you should access the native element and see if there are native possibilities for further styling the element.

Comment: You're right, eventually I went with hiding the header bar (via the native element) and created my own bar and styled it as I needed.